# Is there a way for me to view my Apple Watch Activity data on my mac desktop?

Tags: macos, mac, apple-watch, health.app, activity.app

I'd like to be able to view my apple watch Activity data on my mac desktop or laptop.

So for example, workouts, steps, etc, today, and for the last week, much like what I can find in the Activity app on the apple watch.

I've logged into iCloud.com to see if it was there, but it's not, and I looked for an Activity app on my mac desktop, but don't see one. I've also googled this a bunch, and [found this suggested answer - not supported - on Apple's communities site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7867231#:%7E:text=Apple%20does%20not%20currently%20offer,Apple%20Watch%20on%20your%20Mac.), but would love to find a third party solution to do this, if one exists.

Is there anyway I can see some of my personal health data secured in the health app on my Mac?

Comment: What have you tried already (so we don't suggest ways that you've already attempted)?  What watchOS version?  Please [edit] your question with that info.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've done an EDIT, and added some notes above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not today from Apple. You would need to screenshot images from the iPhone or get a third party app to request permission on iOS and export the data. The health app data is tightly restrained and only interacts with electronic health records and iOS/watchOS apps.

Apple documentation is quite out of date, since the advice on finding compatible apps is no longer correct.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204351

I’ve tried a couple and can not recommend any. Should that change, I’ll edit this answer to say which apps I trust and that do a good job extracting summary data like you requested. I just use my phone for now to review it when I can’t get what I need from my watch itself.

Comment: That page mentions how the data is captured in iCloud, and it can be exported from there with some apps, as you mention. I haven't bought it, but [this app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/health-auto-export-to-csv/id1115567069) sounds like it will auto export the data to CSV, and make it available via icloud

Comment: Yes, I tested a couple csv apps, but their funding source wasn’t one I understood. I hope you can self answer when you get a great option tested. No worry if you take away my check if a better answer arises. Happy app hunting! My hunch is Apple will deliver this next year and most app developers are wary to invest in this space.